# Printing also the duplicate in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I wonder why I don't get the 3 elements of my array.

```
$array1 = array(
        "One" => 1,
        "Two" => 2,
        "One" => 1
    );
```

When I print it:

```
echo 'array1:<pre>'; print_r($array1); echo '</pre>';
```

I get this:

```
array1:
Array
(
    [One] => 1
    [Two] => 2
)
```

This is not what I want. I need to show the following:

```
array1:
    Array
    (
        [One] => 1
        [Two] => 2
        [One] => 1
)
```

Any help wil be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in an array! You can't. Keys must be unique.

Comment: See [*"If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten."*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Just think about it: If you have two elements with the same key how are you going to access one element and not the other?

Comment: You are right. Very obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is a set of key/value pairs. Think of it as a dictionary:

```
array( "elephant" => "Big grey animal with tusks",
       "canary" => "Little Yellow Bird",
       "elephant" => "Candy that tastes like Skittles"
     )
```

When you print this one, you will always get the second definition of "elephant", just like in your code. Try changing the second `"one" => 1` to `"one" => 77`.

Because PHP reads from top-down, the last one will always be the final answer, just like in variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have duplicate keys in an array. So by declaring the `array['one']` you might replace the old value set before for key `array['one']`.

Answer (score 0):

Use array of array..I think you are trying to achieve that..

But this looks weird
    `array(  ['one'] => array(1,3), ['two']=> 2);`